# openpyxl append list starting from a specific cell

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to write the content of my variable starting from a specific cell - ex: d2. The below code writes the content from a1 and I cannot define an offset. Could you please advise?

```
result = SelectRange(2,3)

workbook.create_sheet('data')
sheet = workbook['data']

for item in result:
    sheet.append(item)

workbook.save('example.xlsx')
```

Content of result:

```
[('Data3.1', 'Data4.1', 'Data5.1', 'Data6.1', 'Data7.1'), ('Data3.2', 'Data4.2', 'Data5.2', 'Data6.2', 'Data7.2'), ('Data3.3', 'Data4.3', 'Data5.3', 'Data6.3', 'Data7.3'), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None)]
```

Thanks and Regards
Janos

Comment: If you mean that you want to start from teh second row then you can do `sheet.append([])` before the loop. And if you mean you want to start from the fourth column you can do `sheet.append((None,)*3 + item)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks! Almost what I want! I have a template worksheet with a fix header and a couple of columns at the beginning of the worksheet I have to preserve. So basically, I would like to start the insertion from row 2. Column number depends on the workbook template.  Thanks again!

Comment: The thing is that `append` will always add at the end. So if row 2 is the last you don't need to do nothing special. If you have more rows, you can't use `append`...